# How do i fix this .bat file so it can run in macOS?

Tags: java, macos, shell, batch-file

I have this .bat file created and working perfectly in Windows. When I tried to run this file from macOS terminal, it shows some error.

I've already had JRE installed in my Mac. I also added:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export JAVA_HOME;
```

to my .profile file. All the jars needed are also in a folder beside the .bat file.

This is what's inside the .bat file:

```
shell
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -cp .;libs/*;api-security-generator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar jatis.avantrade.security.securitygenerator.Main
```

I tried deleting the 'java.exe' from code above, but the error still showed up.

I expect to run this .bat file perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to setting `JAVA_HOME` (on macOS) it's better to use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

inside your `~/.profile`. You can also pick any version you like by using `-v` option.

To list all JVM installations, call:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

to select one of them, use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v version)
```

then, you can use it like this

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp .:libs/*:api-security-generator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar jatis.avantrade.security.securitygenerator.Main
```

**turning .BAT to .sh**

you can also create a wrapper script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp .:libs/*:api-security-generator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar jatis.avantrade.security.securitygenerator.Main
```

Make sure to make it executable

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Then, you can call it following way

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: maybe you should add for him to make a .sh file as well. As this would be the equivalent to the bat.

Comment: thanks gonna try this first and will post the result

Comment: this works fine !
thanks Oo.oO and @AlexandarPetrov